# fiter array of objects based on date property

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, ionic-framework, ionic2

i want to display the objects based on current month
my code is

```
 for (let m of  this.monthEvent){
     m=new Date();            
         if(m.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()){
           this.thisMonth=m;
   }
     return this.thisMonth;
```

my array is

```
[{title: "", date: "2018-03-29"},
 {title: "", date: "2018-04-13"},
 {title: "", date: "2018-04-12"},
 {title: "leave", date: "2018-04-11"}
 {title: "", date: "2018-04-16"}]
```

it show m.getTime is not a function

i want to display the current month events

thanks in advance

Comment: `myArray.filter(event => event.date.indexOf('currentMonth') > -1)` try to solve date parsing by yourself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use the function `filter` to get the specific events.
- Get the event's month using this Destructuring assignment `var [_, month] = e.date.split('-');`

```js
var array = [{    title: "a",    date: "2018-03-29"  },  {    title: "b",    date: "2018-04-13"  },  {    title: "c",    date: "2018-04-12"  },  {    title: "leave",    date: "2018-04-11"  },  {    title: "d",    date: "2018-04-16"  }],
    currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1,
    events = array.filter(e => {
        var [_, month] = e.date.split('-'); // Or, var month = e.date.split('-')[1];
        return currentMonth === +month;
    });

console.log(events);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can you explain what is the use of [_, month] = e.date.split('-') over e.date.split('-')[1]; thanks

Comment: @MohammedAbdulkadhir that line gets the month of `"2018-03-29"`, using the function `split` we get something as follow `["2018", "03", "29"]`, the index `1` contains the month.

Comment: hi Ele one more thing how to filter objects based on current month and year